# Does my podcast shed need a vapour barrier

Tags: shed

I'm turning my shed into a small podcast studio. I need to sound proof to an extent (including floor) and wondering if any vapour barrier would be needed. I'm hoping to use it all year round. There will be no heating/cooling. Just body heat effectively.

Comment: Where do you live? What's the weather like there, year round?

Comment: I stay in Scotland. Can be pretty wet and cold during the winter. Not overly hot in summer usually

Comment: I'll leave this to the pros to answer, but I'd say you will have some condensation issues for the winter period if not longer.

Comment: Podcasts are not affected by vapor's.